# # Add datetime values for when the ad was placed

Tags: pandas, datetime-format

I want to use date_posted column to create a new column called ad_placed, featuring the Day of the week, month, and year. What is the proper format? My code is running weekdays as numbers, I want Sunday-Saturday. I also want to add month&date and year. I'm hoping to have it print like Monday March 20, 2020

```
data['ad_placed'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date_posted']).weekday
```

data['ad_placed']

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: I'm not sure what to include in the example to help clarify. An example of date_posted would be 2018-06-23. I have 51525 rows. Should I include the DataFrame as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
df["ad_placed"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date_posted).strftime("%A %B %d, %Y")
```